# Error There is no row at position 1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting an exception

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 1.
   RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)**

There is no row at position can be 0 or 1 or 2 . I guess i am  trying to read or write some array elements which are outside of your array boundary. The code snippet is shown below

```
public void ManageAlarm(string textName, int leaveValue)
{
   try
   {
      int indices = team.Find(textName);
      if (indices >= 0)
      {
         DataRow row = teamTable.Rows[indices];
         row[m_leaveValues] = leaveValue;
      }
   }
```

What should i do here to prevent this alert trace

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the rows count in m_tblAlert before you access rows in it. `m_tblAlert.Rows.Count must be greater then indx`

```
public void ManageDuplicateAlarm(string alertName, int dupValue)
{
   try
   {
      int indx = m_alerts.Find(alertName);
      if (indx >= 0 && m_tblAlert.Rows.Count > indx)
      {
         DataRow row = m_tblAlert.Rows[idx];
         m_dcDuplicates.ReadOnly = false;
         row[m_dcDuplicates] = dupValue;
         m_dcDuplicates.ReadOnly = true;
      }
   }
```

Edit more exlanation on OP comment

You are `checking indx >= 0 to make sure that that -1 could not be row index` for statement m_tblAlert.Rows[idx]; `Similarly you need to check if the value return by m_alerts.Find(alertName) must be valid row number i.e it should not be greater then the number of rows` you have in data table.

Comment: You are checking indx >= 0 to make sure that that -1 could not be row index for statement m_tblAlert.Rows[idx]; Similarly you need to check if the value return by m_alerts.Find(alertName) must be valid row number i.e it should not be greater then the number of rows you have in data table.

Comment: Expected behaviour depends on how it is being handled in code.

Comment: so based on your answer ,if index comes outside boundary, will it skip. That mean do we loss any data

Comment: If index is ouside boundary then you have to revisit the method returning the index. It is a situation that a street has houses from house number 1 to 10 and somebody tells you he lives in house number 12 in that street.

Comment: great explanation, but if i put a condition like m_tblAlert.Rows.Count > 0( means DataTable is not having any rows) insteadof your check, will that sufficient. One more question ,how can we increase datatable count, is there any limitation or how will we know max strength

Comment: I dont know the maximum length of data table might depends on memory (RAM) installed on your machine. Instead of increasing the table size I think you need synchronization (mapping) between table data and results returned by m_alerts.Find(). You might need to search some column values in table instead of index of row.

Comment: sounds good,so the exisitng code which you suggested will not make any harmful i beleive? and if i put a condition like m_tblAlert.Rows.Count > 0( means DataTable is not having any rows) insteadof your check ,which is best?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19795/discussion-between-vettori-and-adil)