# How to fix "There is no row at position 1"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I arranging and extracting data from database to the datagrid, i am trying to custom the column and rows to display the data desired, through the looping i tried to match the data from the one of the datatable to get another data to fill into the datagrid, unfortunately i keep getting "There is no row at position 1 error". I've attached attachment to illustrate the problems faced by me.
[image: Two Illustrations]
[image: Codes]

I've gone through some of the posts in stackoverflow to resolve the problems,i can't find the problems.
1. [Error There is no row at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451380/error-there-is-no-row-at-position-1)
2. [there is no row at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891756/there-is-no-row-at-position-1)

```
    private void generate_view1(DataTable search_data1)
    {
        DataTable sample_data1 = new DataTable();
        sample_data1 = search_data1.Copy();
        sample_data1.Columns.Add("Item_Number");
        sample_data1.Columns.Add("Min_Tolerance");
        sample_data1.Columns.Add("Max_Tolerance");


        var database_select = new DatabaseSelect();
        string OrderNo = Order_NO.Text.ToString();
        DataTable result_data = new DataTable();
        result_data = database_select.LoadTable_DOHEAD(OrderNo);

        string SalesNO = result_data.Rows[0]["EAORNO"].ToString();
        string Del_index = result_data.Rows[0]["EADLIX"].ToString();

        var database_select1 = new DatabaseSelect();
        DataTable result_weight = new DataTable();
        result_weight = database_select.LoadTable_MITTRA(SalesNO, Del_index);


        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = null;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = sample_data1.DefaultView;
        DataGridTextColumn Weight1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        dataGrid1.DisplayMemberPath = sample_data1.Columns["MTTRQT"].ToString();

        Decimal sum = Convert.ToDecimal(sample_data1.Compute("SUM(MTTRQT)", string.Empty));

        Weight.Text = (sum * -1).ToString(); 
         //******Problems occur in below this part*********//
        for (int i = 0; i < sample_data1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string itemcode = sample_data1.Rows[i]["MTITNO"].ToString();
            String ItemNumber = result_weight.Rows[i]["MTITNO"].ToString();

            if (itemcode != " ")
            {
                sample_data1.Rows[i]["Item_Number"] = result_weight.Rows[i]["MTITNO"].ToString();

                var database_select2 = new DatabaseSelect();

                DataTable result_tolerance = new DataTable();
                result_tolerance = database_select.LoadUser_Tolerance(ItemNumber); //** i've include my loadUser Tolerance query in here as well***//
                sample_data1.Rows[i]["Min_Tolerance"] = result_tolerance.Rows[i]["Min_Tol"].ToString();     //*** this is the line where i face the problems***//
                string MINTOL = result_tolerance.Rows[i]["Min_Tol"].ToString();    //*** i've put in this to illustrate the problems**//
                MessageBox.Show(MINTOL);    //*** i've put in this to illustrate the problems**//

            }

        }
```

Updated Additional Information(25/4/2019)
LoadUser_Tolerance variable query( i am trying to select min tolerance from this query to insert it into my datagrid)
For the results desired( you can refer the illustrations above), i only having this issues whenever i tried to get MinTolerance to display in my DataGrid. i can't figure out how to make this right.

```
    public DataTable LoadUser_Tolerance(string ItemNO)
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConString;
        conn.Open();
        CmdString = "SELECT Item_NO, Min_Tol, Max_Tol FROM MasTolerance where Item_NO ='" + ItemNO + "'";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(CmdString, conn);
        OdbcDataAdapter sda = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MasTolerance");
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Debugging Attempts Tried.

```
       if (result_tolerance.Rows.Count > i)
       {
         sample_data1.Rows[i]["Min_Tolerance"] = result_tolerance.Rows[i]["Min_Tol"].ToString();
         string MINTOL = result_tolerance.Rows[i]["Min_Tol"].ToString();
         MessageBox.Show(MINTOL + i);
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error"); //** i can display the Item number in row 1, but Min tolerance for the Row 1 can't be display**//

       }
```

Sorry to make the whole thing this long, but I have no choice.

Comment: You are reading the _i_ row from _result_tolerance_ but you never check if the query from the previous line returns at least _i+1_ rows. Check with rows.Count >= i or explain what you expect the _LoadUser_Tolerance_ returns.

Comment: Most likely result_tolerance only has 1 row, so it only has a row at index 0, not at index 1. Put result_tolerance into a Debug Watch variable and look at it. Most likely it only has 1 row. You should add a check if (result_tolerance.Rows.Count > i) { ... do your stuff here ... } else { .... tell the user there was no match found ... }

Comment: Thanks for the advice man, i will try to figure out again and will update this post soon

Comment: I've tried, but i still can't get to know what is the problem